# How to add matlab integration-spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, matlab

I already installed matlab-mode from the package list. However, not sure
 where to add the path in  ~/.spacemacs. Its a huge file, and the code structure look different from the path file:

```
(autoload 'matlab-mode "matlab" "Matlab Editing Mode" t)
(add-to-list
'auto-mode-alist
'("\\.m$" . matlab-mode))
(setq matlab-indent-function t)
(setq matlab-shell-command "matlab")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to install matlab mode fromt he `extra-langs` layer.
In your `dotspacemacs/configuration-layers` you can add the line: 
`(extra-langs :variables matlab-mode)`.

Maybe this is what you said you did already though.

I don't think you have to add a path to the .spacemacs file. `matlab-mode` should just start up when you open a matlab file in emacs. And if for some reason it doesnt you can enable it with `SPC SPC matlab-mode`.

As to those variables you have though (`matlab-indent-function` and `matlab-shell-command`), they should go in `dotspacemacs/user-config` in the .spacemacs file.

Maybe you can put them in a hook with a function that initializes your matlab variables. The whole thing might look like this:

```
    (defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
      (defun init-matlab ()
        "Initializes my configuration for matlab mode."
        (interactive)
        (setq matlab-indent-function "")
        (setq matlab-shell-command ""))

      (add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook 'init-matlab)
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clear answer. but still I could not run it (searching for program: No such file or directory, matlab

Comment: This layer has been renamed to `major-modes` (without mentioning this in the documentation) six years ago.